# Can a Murdhabhishikta (BrahmKshatriya) man marry a Brahmin girl?

Tags: caste-system, marriage, manu-smriti

Can a Murdhabhishikta (BrahmKshatriya) man marry a Brahmin girl ?

Murdhabhishikta - Child born from Brahmin Father and Kshatriya mother.