# Was wife of Ved-Vyas a Brahmini or Murdhabhishikta?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, caste-system

I am asking this question as I wanted to know if a [Murdhabhishikta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50040/can-a-murdhabhishikta-brahmkshatriya-man-marry-a-brahmin-girl) man can marry a Brahmini girl or not.

Ved-Vyas was a Murdhabhishikta as he had a Brahmin father(Parashara) and Kshatriya mother( Satyavati).

Was the wife of Ved-Vyas , Vatika a Brahmini or murdhabhishikta .

And what about wife of Suka , son of Ved-Vyas , was she also murdhabhishikta ?

**Murdhabhishikta** - [Child of Brahmin father and Kshatriya mother.](https://en.gyaanipedia.com/wiki/Murdhabhishikta)

Answer (score 1):

#### Vyasa's Wife

Most probably she was a pure-Brahimna lady, the daughter of sage Jābāli.
The Skanda Purāṇa doesn't seem to mention any information about her mother.

> [Chapter 147](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502126.html) - Dialogue between Vyāsa and Śuka, Tīrtha-māhātmya,
> Nāgara-khaṇḍa, Skanda Purāṇa
>
> Sūta said:
>
> 1. Further, there is another deity there who is the bestower of sons on men. It is Śiva named Vaṭikeśvara and he dispels all sins.
> 2. O excellent Brāhmaṇas, there Vaṭikā performed a penance formerly, and obtained from Vyāsa a son, Kapiñjala, when Śuka went to the
>    forest.
>
> The sages said:
>
> 3. to 4. **Whose daughter was Vaṭikā?** Why did she perform
>    penance there? Why did Śuka abandon his father and seek refuge in the
>    forest? How did the lady of pure smiles obtain Kapiñjala as son from
>    Vyāsa?
>
> Sūta said:
>
> 5. **O leading Brāhmaṇas, once Vyāsa was inclined to take a wife unto himself though he was devoid of lust**. The noble-souled one was
>    omniscient and quiescent.
> 6. to 7. Once the Kuru race became extinct ending with King Vicitravīrya,
>    O excellent Brāhmaṇas.
>
> Thereupon, at the bidding of Satyavatī, he begot three heroic sons
> including Pāṇḍu in the wives of Vicitravīrya.
>
> 8. Thus while he was in the stage of Vānaprastha, he had a desire for sexual intercourse once. Therefrom the race of Kuru was revived
>    through the sons born of Kṣetra (wives of the dead king Vicitravīrya).
> 9. Then he thought thus, ‘I shall take a wife unto me. Through the rites of a householder, I shall attain excellent goal.’
> 10. **Then he requested Jābāli for his splendid daughter, he immediately gave him his splendid daughter named Vaṭikā.**
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

---

#### Śuka's Wife:

Her name was Pīvarī, and she was most definitely a pure-Brahimna, that too a mind-born daughter, as per the Padma Purāṇa.

> [Chapter 9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364129.html) - Sṛṣṭi-khaṇḍa, Padmapurāṇa
>
> 35. **They (the Barhiṣads) are hundreds of sons of Pulastya**; they are endowed with austerities and concentration of mind.
> 36. They are magnanimous ones and give security to their devotees.
> 37. **Their mind-born daughter is known as Pīvarī. She, a contemplative saint and a divine mother, of abstract meditation**,
>     practised a very severe panance. The lord was pleased with her, and
>     then she asked for a boon.
> 38. “O god, the foremost among the eloquent, if you are pleased, give me a husband possessed of abstract meditation, handsome and one who
>     has controlled his organs of sense”.
> 39. **The lord said: “When Śuka, the master of Yoga (and), Vyāsa’s son, will be born, you, of a good vow, will be his wife.**
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande